# How to generate value in a text box based on two other text boxes without page post back?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I'm working in ASP.NET and have a text box in which I enter First Name of the user. There is another text box in which I enter last name of the user. There is another text box in which I want to create user name based on the first name and the last name such that:

For example 
First Name = Mike
Last Name = Casey
User Name = MCASEY

I want to do this functionality when user entered first name and last name and then click anywhere on the page. I want to do this without page refresh. I am using update panel in my page as well.
Can anyone explain how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to use javascript if you dont' want a page refresh.  something like

```
var firstLetter = $("#first_name").val()[1];
var lastName = $("#last_name").val();
$("#user_name").val((firstLetter+lastName).toUpper());
```

assuming you're using jquery, and assuming your elements have assigned id's that I listed.

Comment: I wrote this in my page: `<script type="text/javascript">
        var firstLetter = $("#txtFirstName").val()[1];
        var lastName = $("#txtLastName").val();
        $("#txtUsername").val((firstLetter + lastName).toUpper());
</script>` but it did not work.

Comment: I put it in a function and then called that function on "onBlur" of first and last text box controls. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UpdatePanel i suppose, you must have wrapped the complete markup inside the `contenttemplate` tag of the UpdatePanel which is causing full page refresh as you described.
Try the below markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpnl" childrenastriggers="true" updatemode="conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
//Add you 3 textbox + some button like check for username here
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<Async ControlId="btnCheck" Event="Click"/>
</Triggers>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: The main problem was not page refresh, the main problem was to implement the functionality as well.

Comment: @asma well then, you can use PageMethods for textbox changed event and then when second textbox loses focus call another page method, get the result and display in 3rd textbox